# ClassCastException class.Accomodation cannot be cast to class.Attraction

Tags: java, polymorphism, classcastexception

These are my mondels:

```
public class Accomodation {
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Attraction extends Accomodation {
    ... 
    private String openingTime;
}
```

I have this method in my `Controller` class:

```
protected Accomodation getAccomodationByFormData(CrudView crudView) {
        Accomodation accomodation = new Accomodation();
        // setters
        return accomodation;
    }
```

which is used within `AttractionController` (which extends previous `Controller`):

```
@Override
    protected Accomodation getAccomodationByFormData(CrudView crudView) {
        Attraction attraction = (Attraction) super.getAccomodationByFormData(crudAttractionView);
        attraction.setOpeningTime(getOpeningTimeWithFormData()); 
        return attraction;
    }
```

in another point of this `AttractionController` I have:

```
...
Attraction attraction = (Attraction) getAccomodationByFormData(crudAttractionView); // throws ClassCastException
...
```

But this is giving me:

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class models.Accomodation cannot be cast to class models.Attraction (models.Accomodation and models.Attraction are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
> at controllers.CrudAttractionController.getAccomodationByFormData(CrudAttractionController.java:302)
> at controllers.CrudAttractionController.lambda$buttonConfermaClicked$4(CrudAttractionController.java:143)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
> at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
> at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
> at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
> at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
> at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
> at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
> at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
> at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
> at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
> at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
> at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
> at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

(Ps. Note that `CrudAttractionView` class extends `CrudView`)

- How can I fix?

**EDIT**

**Attraction**

```
public class Attraction extends Accomodation {
    private String openingTime;

    public Attraction() {

    }

    public Attraction(Accomodation accomodation) {
        super(accomodation);
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

**Accomodation**

```
public class Accomodation implements Serializable {
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected Integer avarageRating;
    protected Integer avaragePrice;
    protected String phoneNumber;
    protected Address address;
    protected Point point;
    protected List<Review> reviews;
    protected Long totalReviews;
    protected Long totalRating;
    protected List<String> images;
    protected boolean hasCertificateOfExcellence;
    protected String addedDate;
    protected String lastModificationDate;

    public Accomodation() {

    }

    public Accomodation(Accomodation accomodation) {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `Attraction` are `Accomodation`, but not all `Accomodation` are `Attraction`.

It means you cannot do safely :

```
Attraction attraction = (Attraction) super.getAccomodationByFormData(crudAttractionView);
```

Even if you are in a `AttractionController` (java doesn't change the return type of super.getAccomadation based on your controller's name).

One solution without the need of any Framework would be to do something like :

```
Accomodation accomodation = super.getAccomodationByFormData(crudAttractionView);
Attraction attraction = new Attraction(accomodation);
attraction.setOpeningTime(getOpeningTimeWithFormData())
```

You just have to make sure you have an `Attraction` Constructor that will take that `Accomodation` and copy it fields to your attraction.

Something like :

```
public Attraction(Accomodation accomodation){
  attraction.setX(accomodation.getX())
  ...
}
```

Or just calling `super(accomodation)` and having a Constructor in `Accomodation` that will be able to copy an Accomodation into a new one (so you'll be able to use that Constructor in all future extending classes)

Now, you ensure your accomodation is effectively an Attraction, then you cast it.

In a more concise example, here is what it would looks like

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class Attraction extends Accomodation {

    public Attraction() {

    }

    public Attraction(Accomodation accomodation) {
        super(accomodation); // we let super do the simple mapping
    }

    // getters and setters

    public void setOpeningTime(String test){
        //

    }
    protected Accomodation getAccomodationByFormData() {
        Accomodation accomodation= new Accomodation();//super.getAccomodationByFormData(crudAttractionView);
        Attraction attraction = new Attraction(accomodation); // we convert our accomodation thanks to our constructor
        attraction.setOpeningTime("...");
        return attraction;
    }
}

class Accomodation implements Serializable {
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected Integer avarageRating;
    protected Integer avaragePrice;
    protected String phoneNumber;
    protected Long totalReviews;
    protected Long totalRating;
    protected boolean hasCertificateOfExcellence;
    protected String addedDate;
    protected String lastModificationDate;

    public Accomodation(Accomodation accomodation) {
        this.id = accomodation.id;
        this.name = accomodation.name;
        this.avarageRating = accomodation.avarageRating;
        this.avaragePrice = accomodation.avaragePrice;
        this.phoneNumber = accomodation.phoneNumber;
        this.totalReviews = accomodation.totalReviews;
        this.totalRating = accomodation.totalRating;
        this.hasCertificateOfExcellence = accomodation.hasCertificateOfExcellence;
        this.addedDate = accomodation.addedDate;
        this.lastModificationDate = accomodation.lastModificationDate;
    }

    public Accomodation() {

    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: if (accomodation instanceof Attraction) is false

Comment: Yes, because right now you are always doing a "new Accomodation();" in your "getAccomodationByFormData" of your Accomodation Controller, which will never be Attraction. 

However, in your AttractionController, you would have to sometimes create "new Attraction()" directly there, and for example copying the informations you've found in the Accomodation to enrich it. But you will not be able to cast it directly

Comment: I've adapted the example for your situation

Comment: Any other solution without invoking the constructor? Because this is giving NullPointerException to other methods

Comment: your problem is you want to do something against java... If you really wanna go this way then you write a convertor method which will convert Accomodation in attraction then pass  your accomodation object to this method before assigning it to attraction

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't use the "Attraction" constructor at ANY point, your code can't know if it's an Attraction or not. Even a conversion method will have to call the "new Attraction" at some point

Comment: actually you gave the example of conversion method . Thing is your edit became visible to me only after I posted my comment.

Comment: @JonathanSchoreels this is giving me many problems such as null pointer exception while invoking get. I'm thinking about an easier solution

Comment: Unfortunately, we are quite in the "easy" part of programming here. Your NullPointerException can be easily debug by checking which variable is Null and dereferenced, and why is it null in the first place (your method returns nothing ? etc ..)

Comment: @JonathanSchoreels Attraction attraction = new Attraction(accomodation); statement returns attraction = null. I can't understand what you mean with "Or just calling super(accomodation) and having a Constructor in Accomodation that will be able to copy an Accomodation into a new one (so you'll be able to use that Constructor in all future extending classes)". I have a constructor in Attraction public Attraction(Accomodation accomodation) { super(accomodation); }

Comment: Yes, but now you have to call it. Here, your `getAccomodationByFormData` returns an object always instantiated with "new Accomodation". It will *never* be an Attraction, and your code won't ever work if you don't convert that "pure" `Accomodation` into an `Attraction`. If you already have that constructor, you can always try `new Attraction(super.getAccomodationByFormData(crudAttractionView))` to re-instantiate a real Attraction.

Comment: I don't understand how that constructor must be. In Attraction I have public Attraction(Accomodation accomodation) { super(accomodation); } but in Accomodation I still have default construcotr

Comment: See my last block quote

Comment: Post all your Accommodation and Attraction code in your original post and I'll do it

Comment: see constructor "public Accomodation(Accomodation accomodation) " and all the redundant line